# MIXIN_WITHOUT_BODY - pug mixins

Tags: gulp, pug

I am new to Pug! been trying to create a simple mixin for nav-item and also am using Gulp 4 for compiling with Gulp-pug package!  It keeps on showing error 'PUG:MIXIN_WITHOUT_BODY' I googled it but nothing. Tell what's wrong in it? is it a syntax error ?

```
mixin nav-item(name, link)
li.nav-item
  a.nav-link(href=link)= name
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of mixins must be indented one level beneath the line that starts with "mixin". Otherwise the mixin declaration is empty.

Write your mixin declaration like this instead:

```
mixin nav-item(name, link)
  li.nav-item
    a.nav-link(href=link)= name
```